# Screen freezes after closing modal (Native-base) (only android)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, native-base

On any screen that I have a modal, always after closing I can't click on anything. The screen completely freezes.
This only happens on android. On IOS it works fine.

sorry for my bad english!!!

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq0Td.gif)

Expo Snack with error: https://snack.expo.dev/@willianferreira/modal-freeze-screen-android

**Remembering that the error only happens on android.
Try to open the modal, close it and then type in the input**

I wish the screen didn't freeze

```
export function BaseModal({ isVisible, onClose, children }: BaseModalProps) {
  return (
    <Modal isOpen={isVisible} onClose={onClose} size="lg">
      <Modal.Content py={4} px={4}>
        <Modal.CloseButton />
        {children}
      </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Comment: Code involving the error  and error messages would make it easier to help you out

Comment: please share your implementation for better understanding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I created this snack to demonstrate => https://snack.expo.dev/@willianferreira/modal-freeze-screen-android

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your snack and the issue arises when you set the `onClose` prop on the modal. You are currently setting the `onClose` to your `setState` function but it does not know how to properly change the state.

Replace `onClose={setModalVisible}` to `onClose={()=> setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}`.